# Titanium mobile statements execution sequence

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have two statements like,

```
var image = selectPhoto();
uploadPhoto(image);
```

I want these statements to be executed in sequence, but this code not working in this way. Both statements are called simultaneously (I guess this is due to multi-theading). How can I solve this issue?

Comment: can you show, your upload syntex...?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is abstract. You should show the code of your functions. However I think you are using HTTPClient in your functions. Titanium statements are executed sequentially except the xhr (HTTPClient object). It always works asynchronously i.e. it sends the request to server and next statements are executed. I think you may have the same problem here. To solve it you can use javascript setTimout function or callbacks as more advanced option.

Comment: selectPhoto() function opens photo gallery to choose a photo and uploadPhoto(image) function uploads that photo to cloud (Appcelerator Cloud).

Comment: Well you can call the upload function in the success callback of opening photogallery. In this way it will only be called after the user successfully selects a photo or you can use setTimeout to put some delay to ensure that a user first select photo and then uploading is done.

Comment: I guess you are using HTTPClient to upload photo. As I said before it always behaves asynchronously. You can only avoid it by imposing delay which is a pathetic solution or you can use callbacks to contorl the asynchronous behavior of xhr object. You can find more about it on Appcelerator Q&A site. This link may give you an idea about using xhr with callbacks: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/141135/pinpoint-only-states-or-provinces-on-mapview